# Print the content of the first file which contains some specific strings

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm searching for a command that prints the contents of the first file found in /etc that contains a string `10.17.1` or `130.236.189` where the commands needed to be used are: `find`, `grep`, `head`, `xargs`, and `cat`.

What I reached before Ravexina's answer and with some help was something like the below.

```
sudo egrep –rl '(10.17.1|130.236.189)' /etc | head -1 | cat
```

Comment: what I reached before Ravexina's answer and with some help was something like the below sudo egrep –rl ‘(10.17.1|130.236.189)’ /etc | head -1 | cat

Comment: Don't forget to escape the periods e.g. `130\.236\.189` otherwise they will be interpreted as regex special characters (which match any single character - not just literal `.`)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this:

```
grep  -lRE  '10.17.1|130.236.189' /etc/ | head -1 | xargs cat
```

- `grep` is used with -R to search `/etc` recursively while using -E to use extended grep features.
- The `-l` switch with grep is used to print only the file names instead of content.
- Then pipe it to `xargs` and xargs feed the file name as parameter tor `cat`
- After all cat will print it out.

If you have to use `find`:

```
find /etc/ 2> /dev/null | xargs grep -lE '10.17.1|130.236.189' 2> /dev/null | head -1 | xargs cat
```

I used `2> /dev/null` to ignore permission errors, when I'm a regular user, If you are using `sudo`, there is no need to use them ;)

Comment: I don't think `stdbuf` is needed here, the pipe will terminate as soon as `head` has read its first line anyway.

Comment: @ByteCommander yeah you are right, updated and thanks ;)

Comment: Synonym: `cat "$(grep  -lRE  '10.17.1|130.236.189' /etc/ | head -1)"`

Comment: @  Ravexina I think the previous version of the command that included find was better.

Comment: @NSH I'm afraid that wasn't working correctly, because the grep was getting it's input from `stdin`, so it was not able to detect the file which contains that specific string.

Comment: @NSH anyway, cleared it a little bit more ;)

Comment: Don't forget to escape the periods e.g. `130\.236\.189` otherwise they will be interpreted as regex special characters (which match any single character - not just literal `.`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could avoid the `head` and `xargs` by using the *exit status* of `grep` as a logical predicate in the `find` command e.g.

```
find /etc -type f -exec grep -IFq -e '10.17.1' -e '130.236.189' {} \; -exec cat {} \; -quit
```

Explanation of the `grep` flags:

- `-I` ignore binary files (usually don't want to be grepping those)
- `-F` treat the patterns as fixed strings rather than regular expressions (avoids the need to escape the periods - at the expense of not being able to use the regex `|` operator)
- `-q` exit immediately  with  zero status if any match is found

The first file in which `grep` finds a match will cause it to exit with zero status, which in turn will cause `find` to execute the `cat` on that file. Assuming the `cat` is successful, `find` will then `quit` so that only the contents of the first matching file are printed.

Comment: can I please know why did you use the curly braces {} ?

Comment: @NSH *"The string '{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command"* - see the `-exec` section of `man find`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q "10\.17\.1\|130\.236\.189" "$1" && printf "\n>>> $1\n" && cat "$1"' sh {} \;
```

The way this works is basically like so:

- we let `find` handle locating files ( `-type f`) and for each one of them executing a command using `-exec  ... {}\;` flag
- that specific command will be in form `bash -c 'command1;command2' arg1 arg2`
- each file that is found is passed as argument to  `bash -c` and within the command itself it is refereed to  as `$1` variable
- `grep -q` will quietly check file for basic regular expression `10\.17\.1\|130\.236\.189` and exit with 0 if text is found or 1 if not found.
- upon successful finding of the text we print file name using `printf` command, and then `cat` the file.

Test run:

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q "10\.17\.1\|130\.236\.189" "$1" && printf "\n>>> $1\n" && cat "$1"' sh {} \;

>>> ./somefile.txt
10.17.1
some other text
>>> ./somefile2.txt
another file, 130.236.189
some other text
```